# CSS margin for Firefox

Tags: html, css, sass

i have written a CSS margin for spacing between checkboxes. It works fine on chrome but not on Firefox.

here is CSS

```
.vehicle-types {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  margin: 6px 0;
  .check-vehicle {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    .checkbox-btn {
      width: auto;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 20px;
      float:left;
      input {
        float:left;
        width:0 !important;
      }
      label {
        margin:0 !important;
        float:left;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

is there any Firefox browser specific CSS?
(screenshots below)
Thanks in advance.

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

Firefox

[image: Mozilla]

Comment: Show us two screenshots one in Chrome and one in Firefox and tell us what's wrong. Until then it looks like a margin issue with firefox and it's a duplicate. Don't use `!important`. It's a bad practise.

Comment: Do you mean Firefox? Mozilla is a company, not a browser.

Comment: wrap checkboxes in the div and use flexbox + `justify-content`. do not use `!important`

Comment: @Vlad Flexbox here is an overkill.

Comment: its Firefox not Mozilla, sorry about that

Comment: Having see the screenshots, flexbox looks like the ideal solution.

Comment: @Vlad i'll check

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman okay, i'm reviewing my code. i'll update once i am done

Comment: @ShashiDharanKrish Is it just width doing a thing? Do you have any sidebars?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman it's working fine on firefox when I set the margin as -5px but not on chrome. if i set it as 0 then it's fine on chrome and not in Firefox.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman yes i have sidebar

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I don't understand how the duplicate is relevant .. there is no relation between both

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can you please help me with this?

Comment: we cannot help with screenshot, we need code

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have added the code.

Comment: not enough as code .. CSS is useless alone, we need a complete code (HTML+CSS) so we can run it and see the output

Comment: What does the inspector tell you about the actual margins/spaces?

Comment: @TemaniAfif You should see the first version of this post.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I saw it and it's still not relevant. He's asking why the code is not working not how to target a particular browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, So I was writing this answer before you pushed your edited post. I am still to go through the code but as an alternate you can try this and see if it works or not

**update:** You have only shared css which is still very difficult to comprehend

An ideal solution to have everything on the same line would be to do.

```css
.parent-div {
display: flex; 
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between
}

.child-div {
align-items: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

.create-box {
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

p {
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div"> 
  <div class="child-div">
   <span class="create-box"> </span>
   <p> checkBox 1 </p>
  </div> 
   <div class="child-div">
   <span class="create-box"> </span>
   <p> checkBox 1 </p>
  </div> 
   <div class="child-div">
   <span class="create-box"> </span>
   <p> checkBox 1 </p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

In the above code I have used **`flex`**

**`flex-direction`** says that wether you want your divs to be stacked in row or columns i.e consider this *somewhat equivalent* to **bootstrap** class `row` . (if you have used bootstrap previously)

**`justify-content: space-between`**: space-between gives equal space between each square, but not between it and the container.

Note: You could have also used space-around

**`Space-around`** puts an equal cushion of space on either side of the square — which means the space between the outermost squares and the container is half as much as the space between two squares (each square contributing a non-overlapping equal amount of margin, thus doubling the space).

**`align-items: center;`** just align everything inside a div to centre across x-y axis

I found this article very useful when learning about [flexboxes](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35) (might help you as well)

Comment: I tried your answer on my code. It just works as charm. You saved my day. Thanks a Ton.

Comment: If this helps you/solves your problem. Upvote/Mark this answered. 
Glad to help you.

Comment: upvoted the answer, its not showing up as my reputation is below 15.

Comment: Mark this answered in that case (Can you see that tick icon?)

Answer (score 1):

Look, the Firefox version adds that margin to the first child as well..

To avoid that, use:

```
.checkbox-btn:not(:first-child) {
  ...
  margin-right: 20px;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of problem also but with IE, for the next time you can use this code
it will only show on firefox, you can edit what you want and it will only show on firefox

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  //just write the code here
     }
```

I know its not a problem from your code but if that was the case you could go to:
https://caniuse.com/

and check if it is your code